# How to read an html table with multiple tbodies with python pandas' read_html?

Tags: python, html, pandas, lxml

This is my html:

```
import pandas as pd    
html_table = '''<table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr><td>1a</td><td>2a</td></tr>
                      </tbody>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr><td>1b</td><td>2b</td></tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>'''
```

If I run `df = pd.read_html(html_table)`, and then `print(df[0]` I get:

```
  Col1 Col2
0   1a   2a
```

Col 2 disappears. Why? How to prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The HTML you have posted is not a valid one*. Multiple `tbody`s is what confuses the `pandas` parser logic. If you cannot fix the input html itself, you have to pre-parse it and ["unwrap"](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) all the `tbody` elements:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_table = '''
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>2a</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1b</td><td>2b</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>'''

# fix HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_table, "html.parser")
for body in soup("tbody"):
    body.unwrap()

df = pd.read_html(str(soup), flavor="bs4")
print(df[0])
```

Prints:

```
  Col1 Col2
0   1a   2a
1   1b   2b
```

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple tbody tag causes the problem when pd.read_html() is called. Having multiple tbody tag is legal in html5 and can be convenient for styling but it looks like it is not supported by pd.read_html(). But if you can just use single `<tbody>` it just works fine.

```
html_table1 = '''<table>
              <thead>
                <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr><td>1a</td><td>2a</td></tr>
                <tr><td>1b</td><td>2b</td></tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>'''

df1 = pd.read_html(html_table1)
print(df1)
[  Col1 Col2
0   1a   2a
1   1b   2b]
```

Comment: The html is not my code. I might read the html with Beautifulsoup and delete all the tbodies before reading with pandas.